# "Convert to character set" doesn't convert tables having only integer columns to specified character set

Tags: mysql, utf-8, mysql-5.6

I am working on 2 servers each having similar configurations, Including mysql variables specific to character set and collation and both are on running mysql server and client 5.6.x. By default all tables are in latin1 including tables with only integer columns, But when I run

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET `utf8` COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci`
```

for all tables in each server only one of the servers is converting all tables to utf8.

**What I already tried:**

Converted the default database character (character_set_database) set to utf8 before running the above listed command

**Solution already worked for me** (but still unsure why it worked)

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHARACTER SET = `utf8` COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci`
```

**Finally there are 2 questions:**

1. `CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET` is working in one server and not in other
2. Solution already worked for me which is similar to `CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET` with only one difference I have come across is, it doesn't implicitly convert the all the columns to specified character set.

Can someone please help me understand what is happening?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post your table schema before and after this command to point out what the issue is? By the way, integers don't have a character set.

Comment: I do know that Integer doesn't have character set. I am not sure how the schema gonna help since I mentioned all Integer columns

Comment: Did the alter without `CONVERT` actually change any text columns?

Comment: @RickJames No It didn't. Pardon me if i didn't convey it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, that was a bug that eventually was fixed.  See bugs.mysql.com .  (The bug probably existed since version 4.1, when `CHARACTER SETs` were really added.)

I prefer to be explicit in two places, thereby avoiding the issue you raise:

- When doing `CREATE TABLE`, I explicitly say what `CHARACTER SET` I need.  This avoids depending on the *default* established when the database was created, perhaps years ago.
- When adding a column (`ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN ...`), I check (via `SHOW CREATE TABLE`) to see if the table *already* has the desired charset.  Even so, I might explicitly state `CHARACTER SET` for the column.  Again, I don't trust the history of the table.

Note:  I am performing these queries from explicit SQL, not from some UI that might be "helping" me.

**Follow on**

@HBK found http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73153 .  From it, I suspect this is what 'should be' done by the user:

```
ALTER TABLE ...
    CONVERT TO ...
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET ...;   -- Do this also
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Rick for your response and thanks for pointing to right place to look at. I think mysql bugs need to be indexed better on google or any search engine, as we expect them to list mysql own domain links in the top when queried but any how very few has a control over it.

Comment: And for others here is the link to Mysql bug report: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73153

Comment: Sveta makes a good point there:  "If you want to change default charset to such table use "default charset=utf8;" instead of "convert"".

Comment: @HBK -- You may notice that I was too lazy to search the bugs.  I much prefer Yahoo search for finding things in the docs:  "site:mysql.com keywords..."